# Error: auth/popup-closed-by-user in Firebase Authentication – How to Resolve Automatically Closed Popup Issue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The issue I'm facing is related to Firebase Authentication, specifically the "auth/popup-closed-by-user" error. When attempting to sign in using Google OAuth with Firebase signInWithPopup, the authentication popup closes automatically, resulting in this error. I need help resolving this issue as it prevents users from signing in successfully.

```js
// Your JavaScript code here
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-auth.js";

// Your Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBpSJx-LfnXfr8as3P2KlKOOxyYuNxK70s",
  authDomain: "slackbot-87889.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "slackbot-87889",
  storageBucket: "slackbot-87889.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "802474881579",
  appId: "1:802474881579:web:ca13a53a1273098548f06e"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
auth.languageCode = 'en';
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

// Function to handle Google sign-in
const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    // Sign in with Google using popup
    const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
    // User signed in successfully
    console.log("User signed in:", userCredential.user);
    // Redirect to desired URL
    window.location.href = "https://61165f2d-6a51-4b11-b1ae-89faf120c23c-00-d5u1itnpfld1.pike.replit.dev/";
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle sign-in errors
    console.error("Error signing in:", error);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const googleLogin = document.getElementById('google-login-btn');
  googleLogin.addEventListener('click', function() {
    handleGoogleSignIn(); // Call the handleGoogleSignIn function on button click
  });
});

I tried implementing the Firebase signInWithPopup method for Google OAuth in my Django web application. I expected the authentication popup to stay open for the user to sign in, but it closed automatically, leading to the "auth/popup-closed-by-user" error.
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the relevant code that is not working as intended? Also have you checked the browser logs while the popup shows and disappears? That might have any clues.